# Как сделать чтоб реакция ставилась под сообщение бота (Дискорд)

Tags: python, discord

Как сделать чтоб реакции ставились не под мое сообщение, а под сообщение бота?
Нужно чтоб реакции бот проставил под свой ембед, а не под мое сообщение

[*код*](https://pastebin.com/dRgCfumB)

как выглядит[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы получить такой результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вы можете вернуть сообщение `message` после отправки сообщения с `embed` и потом уже в это сообщение отправить реакцию.

Пример изменений (будет как на картинке выше):

```py
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def maf(ctx):
    emb = discord.Embed(title=f'Сбор игроков на мафию',
                        description='Ну привет',
                        colour=discord.Color.purple())

    message = await ctx.send(embed=emb) # Возвращаем сообщение после отправки
    await message.add_reaction('✅')
    await message.add_reaction('❌')
    await message.add_reaction('⏭️')
```